# how to show element if visible in view-port with jQuery? (UPDATE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I create a page that have flowing code:
[image]

**UPDATE HTML:**

```
<div class="viewPort">
    <div class="load">
        <div class="item" id="1"></div>
        <div class="item" id="2"></div>
        <div class="item" id="3"></div>
        <div class="item" id="4"></div>
        <div class="item" id="5"></div>
        <div class="item" id="6"></div>
        <div class="item" id="7"></div>
        <div class="item" id="8"></div>
        <div class="item" id="9"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.viewPort {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    width: 500px;
    height: 280px;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: relative;

}
.load {
    width: 900px;
    height: 900px;
}
.item {
    background: yellow;
    /** display: none; **/
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
}
```

**UPDATE jQuery:**

```
$('.load').on('mouseenter','.item',function(){
    //$(this).css('display','block');
    var getID = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(getID);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mr_mohsen_rasouli/6Y29N/1/

and content are hidden! If I enter the mouse into `.item` the `.item` element became visible, that was bad. I decided and try to change the function to that when I scroll and enter item to viewPort become visible?

but everything I tried did not work.

How can I do that?

Comment: The `mouseenter` will never work for the hidden item.

Comment: Here, you can start with this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Y29N/). *(All I did was paste your current code...)*

Comment: I know @Sid M, I said thad in my last version I did that. now i vat to use scroll for that but I don't know how? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Viewport Selectors plugin for jQuery. It's pretty straightforward.
Here's the link:

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport

You can use it like this:

```
$('.element').each(function(){
    if( $(this).is(':in-viewport') ){
        $(this).fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I may suggest you to use **opacity** instead of **display**. Check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reVgR/)

```
$('.item').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('opacity','1');
});
```

And change the css to

```
.item {
    background: yellow;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: TnX, but @Arvind i wanna when I scroll and Item enter too veiwPort that become visible...